# Regarding topic candidate list for topic modeling analysis (LDA)

Tags: bayesian, text-mining

I am confused on one issue of topic modeling analysis. When  we perform the topic modeling analysis over a collection of documents, do we need to provide a set of topic candidate list as the input for the analysis? Or the resulting topics are just extracted from the input documents themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting topics are just extracted from the input documents themselves.

Document are distributed over topics, and topics are distributed over words, so you can explain topics by top-words.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I have a pre-existing topic list, and would like to ensure that all of the generated topic come from this list? Can LDA incorporate this kind of constraint or I have to use other algorithms?

Comment: If you pre-existing topic are just words, you can refer Tag LDA or Labeled LDA, just google it. As far as I known, in LDA you can't do that, even you pre-set the topics(distribution over words), it will converges with new topics set. But if you have topics already, why do you need LDA? or you can just fit document to topics?